# Python How to get set bit

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bit

Say I have a number that in memory looks like this (or similar, I don't know exactly how Python stores numbers):

```
0000 0000 0000 1000
```

I want to get what bit is set (Thanks to @muddyfish, I will clarify that these numbers will have only one bit set), in this case 3, because 2^3 = 8. I could just use log2 to achieve this, but this seems like something that could easily be solved by 'bit twiddling' techniques. I could also loop through all the bits like this:

```
def getSetBit(num):
    if num == 0:
        return -1

    bit = 0
    while num != 1:
        bit += 1
        num >>= 1

    return bit

# getBitSet(0b100000) == 5
# getBitSet(1) == 0
```

However this to me seems awkward and slower than it should be. If this is the only way to do this, I guess I could live with it, but I would like it if it wasn't.

Comment: Do you only want to test values with 1 bit set?

Comment: @muddyfish yes, indeed

Comment: In general you could perform a binary search on any fixed length integer (list of bits) by recursively masking against the appropriate constants (0x0000ffff and 0x0ffff0000 at the stop of the function call for 32-bit integers, and so on).

This would find all the set bit in log(n) time for n-bits ... (where n is length, in bits, of some supported integer type in your language).  It would work at m*log(n) time for arrays of n-bit integers which would, effectively, be linear time for long integer arrays (because log(n) is constant for any fixed bit length).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the bit number of the highest bit set, you could use

```
int.bit_length()-1
```

This is much more efficient then using `math.log()` or the other function you had posted

EDIT:

As requested, timeit results are posted:

> python -m timeit -s 'import math;x=100' 'int(math.log(x,2))'
>
> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.5 usec per loop
>
> python -m timeit -s 'i = 100' 'i.bit_length()-1'
>
> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.106 usec per loop

Also, using `math.log` will yeild inaccurate results for values higher than 2**29.

Comment: This is a great answer, but do you have anything that is more language independent?

Comment: well, for example C doesn't have this function natively, along with other languages. What is a way I could do this that most other languages would be able to do also?

Comment: A while loop with shifting? I wouldn't know for a language I don't know

Comment: This is actually wrong, you need  `num.bit_length() -1`

Comment: I guess I'll look at the source to see what the Pythonistas did for `int.bit_length()`. Thanks!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That better?

Comment: @muddyfish Based on what you say it is much more efficient than using math.log?

Comment: @chromano I've added timeit results to my answer for comparison

Comment: While your speed ranking is correct, your timings aren't isolating the operations that you want to time. What you actually want is `python -m timeit -s 'i = 100' 'i.bit_length()-1'` and `python -m timeit -s 'from math import log' 'log(100,2)'`. With these timings, `.bit_length()` takes `0.0592 usec per loop` and `log()` takes `0.146 usec per loop`.

Comment: I've also added the `int` function to the test because that was what the OP wanted anyway